# VSCode + CMake + GDB (under Windows): Incomplete debug symbols?

Tags: c++, cmake, gdb

Unfortunately, I currently have the phenomenon that I have a very strange debug environment. For example, with the GDB, I see incomplete content of the local variables. Everything that ends up on the stack is apparently displayed. Everything that ends up in the heap is no longer visible. How can that be?

I'm compiling on Windows 10.
I use the following environment:

- VS Code 1.71.2 + CMake Tools
- CMake 3.24.2
- GNU Compiler GCC 11.2.0 (from my Qt6 Installation, correct detected from CMake)

I compiled a very small C++ test program:

1x under VS Code and 1x under Visual Studio 2019

```
class classA
{
public:
    classA(int a, int b) : myA(a), myB(b)
    {

    }

private:
    int myA, myB;
};

int main()
{
    uint8_t testA = 0;
    uint16_t testB = 88;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<classA>> listOfClassA;

    listOfClassA.push_back(std::make_unique<classA>(3, 7));
    listOfClassA.push_back(std::make_unique<classA>(10, 11));
    listOfClassA.push_back(std::make_unique<classA>(12, 13));
}
```

If I debug this and set a corresponding breakpoint (at last line of main()), the debug symbols are complete under Visual Studio 2019 and the display of the local variable looks much better.
I can't work properly with the display under VS Code.

Here are the according screenshots of the comparation:

[VS 2019 with complete debug information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v7qG.jpg)

[VS Code without information about the local variable listOfClassA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88FCr.jpg)

The content of my CMake Configuartion (CMakeLists.txt) looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(STL_example VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(STL_example main.cpp)
```

I've already played around with countless compiler flags, e.g. -ggdb -g3, unfortunately without success.
I specified the information in my CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
add_compile_options(
  "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0;-g3>"      # no optimization, maximal debug informations for gdb       
  "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O2>"                # optimization level 2 --> O1 plus instruction scheduling --> best for release versions
)
```

Something is wrong there...

I don't know how to solve this problem anymore.
Would be great if someone else had a hint so I can get a plausible view of my variables in the Debug window under VS Code.

Thank you so much.

**Annotation:**

I start debugging under VS Code by simply clicking on the small bug at the bottom of the CMake tool status bar.
Debug is of course selected as the currunt build variant.

Here I can also see in the terminal that GDB from the QT6 installation is then used.

```
--dbgExe=C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/bin/gdb.exe'
```

That should all be correct...

Comment: Debug build (unoptimized and with debugging symbols) or release build (optimized code without debug symbols (or challenged debug info))? Debugging optimized code without debug symbols can be *hard*. With debug symbols it can be a little easier but still confusing. For the best debugging experience you want unoptimized code with debug info

Comment: Yes, that's right. I also tried to achieve this with the following statement in my CMakeLists.txt
"$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O0;-g3>"

Comment: Have you tried it with gdb only, without VS-code?

Answer (score 1):

Now I tried **debugging with gdb manually** in the console. I set a breakpoint at the same location (end of main()) and try to print the content of the std::vector<> listOfClassA.

Here is the result:

> (gdb) print listOfClassA

```
$1 = std::vector of length 2, capacity 2 = {Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'>: Request for member '_M_head_impl' is ambiguous in type 'std::tuple<classA*, std::default_delete<classA> >'. Candidates are:
  'std::default_delete<classA> std::_Head_base<1, std::default_delete<classA>, true>::_M_head_impl' (std::tuple<classA*, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Tuple_impl<0, classA*, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Head_base<1, std::default_delete<classA>, true>)
  '<unnamed type> std::_Head_base<0, classA*, false>::_M_head_impl' (std::tuple<classA*, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Tuple_impl<0, classA*, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Head_base<0, classA*, false>)
{_M_t = {<std::__uniq_ptr_impl<classA, std::default_delete<classA> >> = {_M_t = std::tuple containing = {[1] = 0x2590c4a4240,
          [2] = {<No data fields>}}}, <No data fields>}}, Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'>: Request for member '_M_head_impl' is ambiguous in type 'std::tuple<classA*, std::default_delete<classA> >'. Candidates are:
  'std::default_delete<classA> std::_Head_base<1, std::default_delete<classA>, true>::_M_head_impl' (std::tuple<classA*, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Tuple_impl<0, classA*, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Tuple_impl<1, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Head_base<1, std::default_delete<classA>, true>)
  '<unnamed type> std::_Head_base<0, classA*, false>::_M_head_impl' (std::tuple<classA*, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Tuple_impl<0, classA*, std::default_delete<classA> > -> std::_Head_base<0, classA*, false>)
{_M_t = {<std::__uniq_ptr_impl<classA, std::default_delete<classA> >> = {_M_t = std::tuple containing = {[1] = 0x2590c4a4670,
          [2] = {<No data fields>}}}, <No data fields>}}}
```

Can anyone interpret these informations?
What I see so far is that there are a lot of "No data fields -  declarations"...
What means the "Python Exception with gdb.error" in this context?

Thank you so much...